# Silverstripe: How to sort a PaginatedList

Tags: php, sorting, pagination, reverse, silverstripe

I am trying to sort a Paginated List of ArticlePages. 
Article Pages have a 'Date' field I want to use for the sorting. The pagination works but the sorting doesn't. What am I missing? Thx a lot!

According to the API/ PaginatedList http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-PaginatedList.html
there is a sort() Method http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SS_ListDecorator.html#_sort

ArticlePage.php

```
class ArticlePage extends Page {

    private static $db = array(
        'Place' => 'Text',
        'Date' => 'Date',
    );
```

ArticleHolder.php

```
class ArticleHolder_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function PaginatedArticles(){
        $paginatedItems = new PaginatedList(ArticlePage::get(), $this->request);    
        $paginatedItems->sort('Date DESC');
        $paginatedItems->setPageLength(4);
        return $paginatedItems;
    }
```

ArticleHolder.ss

```
<% loop $PaginatedArticles %>
    <% include ArticlePage %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $paginatedItems->sort() method should work. Could you check that your records actually have Date values and that they're as expected?

An other way to do this:

PHP

```
$paginatedItems = new PaginatedList(ArticlePage::get()->sort("Date DESC"), $this->request);
```

Comment: Sorting right after the ArticlePage::get() method works!
The latter, sorting in the template breaks the pagination, meaning more than the limit of 4 pages are shown. Thx!